# Rails comments gem Acts_as_commentable on pins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pins, acts-as-commentable

I have a rails app where users can upload pins, I want to use the `[acts_as_commentable_gem][1]` to allow users to comment pins, here is my config:

**app/models/pin.rb**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_commentable 
end
```

**app/controlers/pins_controller.rb**

```
def show
   @pin.find params[:id]
   @comment = @pin.comments.new
end
```

**app/views/pins/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag "/pins/add_new_comment" do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "id", post.id %>
    <%= text_area_tag "comment[comment]" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Pin Comment" %>
    <% end %>
```

**app/models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActsAsCommentable::Comment

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  default_scope -> { order('created_at ASC') }

  # NOTE: install the acts_as_votable plugin if you
  # want user to vote on the quality of comments.
  #acts_as_voteable

  # NOTE: Comments belong to a user
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**app/controllers/pin_controller.rb**

```
def add_new_comment
    pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    pin.comments << Pin.new(params[:comment])
    redirect_to :action => :show, :id => pin
end
```

**finally in my config/routes**

```
get "/pins/add_new_comment" => "pins#add_new_comment", :as => "add_new_comment_to_pins", :via => [:pin]
```

But I run to a routing error:

**undefined local variable or method `acts_as_commentable' for PinsController:Class**

I am really not sure where this error come from, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure but you route shouldn't be like

```
get "/pins/:id/add_new_comment" => "pins#add_new_comment", :as => "add_new_comment_to_pins"
```